# Is CoStandard Deviation a thing?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, covariance-matrix

So there's Standard Deviation, Variance, and Covariance, but is there a co standard deviation?

If not why not? Is there a fundamental mathematical reason or is it just convention?

If so why is it not used more, or at least really hard to find using Google searches?

I don't mean this to be a flippant question, I'm trying to really question statistics rather than just memorize a bunch of formulas.

Comment: Could you clarify what you think a "co standard deviation" would represent?  Is there some underlying motivation, or are you just asking (in a meta sense) whether there might be some universal meaning to prepending "co" to the name of any statistic?

Comment: I'm assuming the OP is generalizing from variance:covariance ::  standard deviation: "costandard deviation", but it wouldn't hurt for the question to be more explicit (assuming they really do mean $\sqrt{\sigma_{XY}}$).

Comment: I've got a slightly different formulation of this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984405/how-to-find-standard-deviation-error-bound-from-variance-error-bound

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One useful property of the standard deviation is that it has the same units as the mean, so the magnitudes of $\sigma_X$ and $\bar X$ are directly comparable.  I've never seen anyone compute the co-standard deviation (by which I assume you mean the square root of the covariance); if the units of $X$ and $Y$ are denoted as $[X]$ and $[Y]$, then the units of the covariance are $[X][Y]$ and the units of the co-standard deviation would be $\sqrt{[X][Y]}$, which isn't particularly useful (unless $X$ and $Y$ have the same units). On the other hand, the *correlation* $\sigma_{XY}/(\sigma_X \sigma_Y)$ is unitless, and is a very common scale for reporting associations.

The variance (in contrast to the standard deviation) is useful because it generally has nicer mathematical properties; in particular

$$
\sigma^2_{X+Y} = \sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Y + 2 \sigma_{XY},
$$
which simplifies nicely when $X$ and $Y$ are independent (hence $\sigma_{XY}=0$).

While you're thinking about ways of scaling variances you could also consider the *coefficient of variation* $\sigma_X/\bar X$ (which is unitless), or the variance-to-mean ratio $\sigma^2_X/\bar X$ (which has weird units but is meaningful in the context of a count distribution such as the Poisson, which is also unitless).

Comment: Good points, but it does not seem to answer why taking square root of covariance doesn't make sense.

Comment: Here's one way to exploit your formula: use it to observe that the covariance can be *defined* as $$\sigma_{XY} = (\sigma^2_{X+Y}-\sigma_X^2-\sigma_Y^2)/2.$$ So why not then simply define a "co-SD"--let's call it $\tau$, say--as $$\tau_{XY}=(\sigma_{X+Y}-\sigma_X-\sigma_Y)/2?$$ This hints at the difficulty of answering the original question without knowing what the "co" of anything might possibly mean: you can't demonstrate much just by showing that one particular generalization is nonsense or useless; you have to consider *all* possible ways to generalize a concept!

Comment: If the units of $X$ and $Y$ are the same, then $\sqrt{[X][Y]} = [X] = [Y]$. $X$ and $Y$ could also be non-negative. Perhaps on certain pairs of variables there is something to work with here.

Answer (score 5):

The question seems back-to-front. In mathematics we don't invent names for quantities "just because we can", but because the named quantity is *useful* for something.

The OP's question doesn't give and reasons why he/she thinks there is a useful quantity that might be named "coStandard Deviation" and the answers are guessing at things that *might* be useful.

To generalize the concept to multi-variable linear regression with $n$ variables, the "covariance" becomes an $n \times n$ symmetric *matrix*. You can certainly make a sensible definition of the "square root of a symmetric matrix" so long as it is positive definite or semi-definite, but it's hard to think of a use for it in this context - and it *isn't* the same as taking the square root of each *term* of the matrix separately!

Of course the square root of a *diagonal* matrix (e.g. the variance matrix) is just the square root of the individual terms, so the concept of "standard deviation" does generalize in an obvious and useful way - but "coStandard Deviation" doesn't, IMO. And in general, the "square root of a matrix" isn't even uniquely defined, so which particular square root do you want to choose as the coStandard Deviation?

Comment: G. H. Hardy's [*A Mathematician's Apology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician%27s_Apology) is a prominent historical example of the attitude that some mathematicians have toward 'useful for something' mathematics.

Comment: This [excerpt from Feynman's lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obCjODeoLVw) is instructive on the distinction between mathematics and Physics, and the relationship between mathematics and other disciplines can sometimes be considered in a similar way.

Answer (score 4):

Covariance can be both positive and negative.

So the square root of the covariance could be real or imaginary.

You can compare a real number with an imaginary number for size. The units for "standard co-deviation" would be inconvenient. There's no benefit in taking the square root.

Comment: Please see [my comment to Ben Bolker's answer.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308225/is-costandard-deviation-a-thing#comment585785_308226)